# mysql + show tables and insert a row number for each table

Tags: mysql

this command shows the tables.

```
mysql> show tables like '%xyz%';
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_XYZ (%xyz%) |
+------------------------------+
| xyz2                         |
| xyz23                        |
| xyz23_linuxLineEnding        |
+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**What command is there to insert an index number each table e.g.**

```
+----+------------------------------+
| id | Tables_in_XYZ (%xyz%)        |
+----+------------------------------+
|  1 | xyz2                         |
|  2 | xyz23                        |
|  3 | xyz23_linuxLineEnding        |
+----+------------------------------+
```

---

### EDIT1 - this is close

```
mysql> select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name LIKE '%xyz%';
+------+-----------------------+
| id   | table_name            |
+------+-----------------------+
| NULL | xyz2                  |
| NULL | xyz23                 |
| NULL | xyz23_linuxLineEnding |
+------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

### EDIT2 - this is what I want

```
mysql> set @rn :=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name LIKE '%xyz%';
+------+-----------------------+
| id   | table_name            |
+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | xyz2                  |
|    2 | xyz23                 |
|    3 | xyz23_linuxLineEnding |
+------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why? The schema is accessible as tables in the mysql database, and the database + table name constitutes a unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `information_schema.tables`:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, table_name
from information_schema.tables cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
where table_name like '%xyz%';
```

Comment: that seems to give tables + other stuff I am not familiar with e.g. `CHARACTER_SETS, COLLATIONS,COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY ...`. Can I narrow this down? I tried this `select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, table_name like '%xyz%' from information_schema.tables cross join (select @rn := 0) params;` but that just show `1` where the criteria is met.

Comment: @HattrickNZ That's because of your MySql version, I had this kind of problems in the past using this technique. MySql 5.6 seems to work and below that you have to define a variable outside of the query. See my question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117449/really-strange-behavior-using-variables-in-mysql-query

Comment: tks think I got it see edit 2. But can that work in this form as having issues with this `$sql="SET @rn :=0; SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, table_name from information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%xyz%'";`